# Obter total de registro encontrados durante uma busca

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo uma página HTML que contem uma **tabela** e um **campo de busca**. A tabela é filtrada enquanto o usuário digita.Ate ai tudo bem. Mas Gostaria que fosse exibido o total de registros retornados pela busca. tipo assim: "Foram encontrados x itens". preciso que esse numero mude conforme a digitação no campo de busca.
o CTRL+F faz exatamente o que eu preciso. ele faz essa contagem.
tentei com Javascript mas não consegui.

```js
$('input#txt_consulta').quicksearch('table#tabela tbody tr');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.quicksearch/2.3.1/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="form-group input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
 <input name="consulta"  id="txt_consulta" placeholder="Consultar" type="text" class="form-control">
 <br>
 foram encontrados "x"  itens.
</div>
 <table id="tabela" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
   <th>Time</th>
   <th>País</th>
   <th>Capital</th>
   <th>Torneio</th>
   
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Liverpool</td>
    <td>Inglaterra</td>
    <td>Londres</td>
    <td>Premier League</td> 
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Chelsea</td>
    <td>Inglaterra</td>
    <td>Londres</td>
    <td>Premier League</td> 
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Manchester City</td>
    <td>Inglaterra</td>
    <td>Londres</td>
    <td>Premier League</td> 
   </tr>
   
   
  </tbody>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aqui já é um caminho: `var total = $('table#tabela tbody tr:visible').length;`

Comment: valeu mesmo  NoobSaibot. funcionou mano! Obrigado mesmo cara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do plugin](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch), você pode usar o callback `onAfter` para contar quantas linhas estão visíveis na tabela quando digitar algo no campo de busca.

Para contar as linhas visíveis, use o código sugerido pelo amigo @NoobSaibot:

```
$('table#tabela tbody tr:visible').length;
```

Mas é preciso criar um elemento com um `id` que irá receber essa informação. No lugar de `foram encontrados "x"  itens.`, coloque um `span` com um `id`:

```
<span id="num_res"></span>
```

E no callback do `onAfter` você conta as linhas visíveis e joga o texto com o resultado dentro dessa span, podendo até ajustar o texto no singular ou plural, dependendo do número do resultado:

```js
$('input#txt_consulta').quicksearch('table#tabela tbody tr', {
   'onAfter': function () {
      var total = $('table#tabela tbody tr:visible').length;
      if(total == 0){
         var txt_res = "Nenhum item encontrado.";
      }else if(total < 2){
         var txt_res = 'Foi encontrado "'+ total +'" item.';
      }else{
         var txt_res = 'Foram encontrados "'+ total +'" itens.';
      }
      $("#num_res").text(txt_res);
   }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.quicksearch/2.3.1/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="form-group input-group">
 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
 <input name="consulta"  id="txt_consulta" placeholder="Consultar" type="text" class="form-control">
 <br>
 <span id="num_res"></span>
</div>
 <table id="tabela" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
   <th>Time</th>
   <th>País</th>
   <th>Capital</th>
   <th>Torneio</th>
   
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Liverpool</td>
    <td>Inglaterra</td>
    <td>Londres</td>
    <td>Premier League</td> 
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Chelsea</td>
    <td>Inglaterra</td>
    <td>Londres</td>
    <td>Premier League</td> 
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Manchester City</td>
    <td>Inglaterra</td>
    <td>Londres</td>
    <td>Premier League</td> 
   </tr>
   
   
  </tbody>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: funcionou Sam. obrigado. valeu pela ajuda. Só faltava isso pra fechar o sistema. "a priori" kkk